# Make the URL path count backwards

Tags: php, count, parse-url

I learned how to parse an URL and return me a specific part of it.

For now, I'm currently working in a localhost server, which contains a long basename:
`localhost/mydocs/project/wordpress/mexico/cancun`

If I want to get the word `mexico` I would have to count 4 until there.

```
$url   = localhost/mydocs/project/wordpress/mexico/cancun
$parse = parse_url($url); 
$path  = explode('/', $parse[path]);
echo   = $path[4]
```

Even though it works fine for localhost, when uploading in the server, the basename get shorter and the number 4 can not reach `mexico`, because the URL becomes:
`example.com/mexico/cancun`

I'd like to know if there is a global solution for it. I thought about counting backwards, like using -2, so it would start counting from the word "cancun", but I don't know whether is possible or not!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$path[count($path)-2]` `-2` being the configurable part.

Note this will only work for numeric indices, like for your case.